# White Screen comes for sometime before loading the Azure login page

Tags: ios, azure-mobile-services

I am using azure for my iOS application. At first controller on login click i am calling the azure's login service.

```
[client loginWithProvider:@"xxxxx" controller:self animated:YES completion:^(MSUser *user, NSError *error)
```

Before loading the Azure login page i could see a white screen for some 5-6 seconds.

Is it possible to resolve and if yes how? Do we need to change in Azure SDK for iOS.

Comment: I have never used Azure sdk so a dumb question, is that page located in a webview? Or does it open your web browser for that? The login page?

Comment: Its loaded in a webview. We have tried changing in the webView but still White screen is still appering.

Comment: What changes have you tried? You know webview will have to load the page first right? Why not show an activity indicator till it loads the page to show that hey I am loading, please wait.

Comment: I get the same, did you resolve this?

Comment: Yes i have resolved this. Will post the answer for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure SDK (https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/sdk/), Open the iOS Project and navigate to MSLoginView.m. Edit the initWithFrame method to below one. Regenerate the framework file and import into your project.

```
-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
         client:(MSClient *)client
       startURL:(NSURL *)startURL
         endURL:(NSURL *)endURL
     completion:(MSLoginViewBlock)completion;
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Capture all of the initializer values as properties
        client_ = client;
        startURL_ = startURL;
        endURL_ = endURL;
        endURLString_ = endURL_.absoluteString;        
        completion_ = [completion copy];

        // Create the activity indicator and toolbar
       activityIndicator_ = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
     initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
       activityIndicator_.alpha = 1.0;
       activityIndicator_.center = CGPointMake([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width/2, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height/2);
       [self addSubview:activityIndicator_];

       toolbar_ = [self createToolbar:activityIndicator_];
        [self addSubview:toolbar_];

        // Set the toolbar defaults
        showToolbar_ = NO;
        toolbarPosition_ = UIToolbarPositionBottom;

        // Create the webview
        webView_ = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
        [webView_ setOpaque:NO];
        webView_.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        webView_.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
        webView_.scrollView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
        [webView_.scrollView setBouncesZoom:NO];//disable ZOOM Functionality
        webView_.scalesPageToFit = YES;
        webView_.delegate = self;
        [self addSubview:webView_];
        webView_.hidden =YES;


        // Call setViewFrames to update the subview frames
        [self setViewFrames];

        // Start the first request
        NSURLRequest *firstRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:startURL];
        [webView_ loadRequest:firstRequest];
    }
    return self;
}
```

@user203538: Let me know if you get the desired output

Comment: how do you modify the .m files? I only see the headers .h in the framework.

Comment: You can download the source code from https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services which has framework for different platforms. Goto sdk -> iOS and open the xcodeproj. Modify the above file, save and close the project. Then in the same hierarchy there is a file build.command, double click that to generate the updated framework.Use the framework into your project.

Comment: I tried rebuilding the GitHub project but I then just an error when I try and create a MSLoginController. It's almost like the project on GitHub is not the same as the one you download via azure portal.

I did try and post this originally as a comment, but didn't work on my phone

Comment: It seems to be another peoblem. Can you create a new question with error, screenshots, links, details...